# Tem como ler um json e pegar todas as strings sem saber o que tem lá dentro?

Tags: android, json

Estou fazendo um formulário dinâmico onde recebo um `Json` e crio um formulário dinâmico, está tudo automatizado, menos a parte que tenho que extrair cada *`string`* do `JSon` e colocar dentro de um *`array`*.

Comment: Qual o problema de saber o que tem dentro do JSON? “string”, pra você, inclui as chaves dos objetos dentro do JSON?

Comment: @daniel12345smith não há problema em não saber quai são os valores, desde que saiba quais são as chaves. tem como postar o que você tem até agora para ficar mais fácil de te ajudar?

Comment: "{\"nome\":\"nome\",\"sobrenome\":\"sobrenome\",\"idade\":\"idade\",\"endereco\":\"endereco\",\"pais\":\"pais\"}" Eu estou usando o jo.getString("nome") por exemplo, e colocando dentro de um vetor de string, tem como eu colocar no vetor sem saber se dentro do json existiria a string "nome"?

Answer (score 0):

Pense dessa maneira:

Isso é um objeto: `{ }`, e isso é um array: `[]`

Toda saída "JSON" é considerada um objeto. Mesmo o array em JavaScript é visto com um objeto só que do tipo Array.

No caso, quando você recebe uma coleção em "JSON" com chaves e atribui um nome para estas chaves:  `var obj = { nome: "x", id: "y" }` a forma correta de acessar seus valores "x" e "y" é chamando o objeto desta maneira: obj.nome, obj.id. O mesmo pode ser feito de outra forma, como é feito no array, entretanto isso é válido em casos em que as chaves serão dinâmicas: `obj["nome"]; obj["id"];`

Agora pense que se você quer receber um JSON como uma string, é o mesmo que ignorar todas estas regras. Então basta você receber todo o objeto, e convertê-lo para uma string, para isso use o método `JSON.stringify(obj)`;

Comment: Desculpe amigo, mas discordo, `{0: x, 1: y}` não é interpretado com array, pois senão ele suportaria `.length` a não que você esteja falando de tecnologias diferente do JavaScript que tentam interpretar Json. Outra coisa, o que o autor pediu foi como extrair o json com android então provavelmente a duvida dele é sobre Java e não sobre a diferença de Object e Array, sugiro que edite a resposta amigo.

Comment: Concordo, já editei o texto, obrigado.