# Como ler um Json sem saber o que tem dentro dele ou a quantidade de dados?

Tags: java, android, json

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário dinâmico para Android no qual você recebe um arquivo Json e cria os formulários. Está tudo automatizado, com exceção da parte que tenho que pegar uma string na mão do Json. Existe um modo de ler a string sem setar o nome dela dentro do `.getString`?

```
"{\"nome\":\"nome\",\"sobrenome\":\"sobrenome\",\"idade\":\"idade\",\"endereco\"‌​:\"endereco\",\"pais\":\"pais\"}"
```

Eu estou usando o `jo.getString("nome")` por exemplo, e colocando dentro de um vetor de string, tem como eu colocar no vetor sem saber se dentro do json existiria a string "nome"?

Comment: Se possível apague essas duas perguntas: [**1**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69579/6454) e [**2**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69568/6454) quando for necessário colocar uma nova informação a respeito do teu problema, não é necessário criar uma nova pergunta, existe um recurso mágico chamado **editar** que fica entre **"Compartilhar"** e **"fechar"**. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), veja também: [**Como fazer uma boa pergunta?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  e [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: O que é `jo`? Um `org.json.JSONObject`? Poste um pedaço do seu código.

Answer (score 2):

Se a estrutura do *Json* for sempre a mesma pode fazer um *Parser* utilizando a classe [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

Para o exemplo que postou seria assim:

```
public ArrayList<String> getValuesFromJson(String jsonString) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        reader.nextName();
        String value = reader.nextString();
        values.add(value);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Para utilizar use:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"nome\":\"Paulo\",\"sobrenome\":\"Sousa\",\"idade\":\"25\"}";
    ArrayList<String> lista;
    try {
        lista = getValuesFromJson(jsonString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```